# push to array as long as the item does not already exist in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have ready many post on this but none of them seem to help me out with my problem or i don't understand their answer in a way to convert it to my script. I want to add a item to an array from the input as long as it does not already exist in the array. please any help is greatly appreciated.

i would imagine i need to use a for loop and then compare the new item to the existing items in the array to check if the item already exist.

```
    var Fruit = ['apple', 'bannanna', 'rasberry', 'watermelon', 'grape', 'orange'];

    $('#addFruit').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var val = $('#fruitAdd').val();
      Fruit.unshift(val);
      console.log(Fruit);
    });

HTML
   <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="fruitAdd" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="addFruit" class="btn btn-default search">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: Why not use an associative array? That way you can check if you already have it quickly

Comment: There are no associative arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use loop, I thinkg the code will look like it.

```
 var Fruit = ['apple', 'bannanna', 'rasberry', 'watermelon', 'grape', 'orange'];

$('#addFruit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var flag = true;
  var val = $('#fruitAdd').val();
  for(var i = 0 ; i < Fruits.length ; i ++){
      if(Fruits[i] == val)
         flag = false;
  }
  if(flag)
      Fruits.push(val);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if an item exists in an array by checking for it's index:

```
var fruit = ['apple', 'banana'];
if (fruit.indexOf('cherry') === -1) {
    console.log('No cherries here');
}
```

So using that, you can write something like this:

```
var val = $('#fruitAdd').val();
if (Fruit.indexOf(val) === -1) {
    Fruit.push(val);
}
```

Comment: Since he's using jQuery, `$.inArray()` would give some additional portability.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to declare `fruit` as an object literal and add properties:

```
fruit = {'apple': true, 'banana': true};
var val = $('#fruitAdd').val();
fruit[val] = true;
```

Comment: In this case looping over the values in the object is less intuitive than with an array but yeah that works.

Comment: No looping is necessary in this case.

Comment: Just try to add the property; if it exists, nothing changes.